# Does our brain emit any kind of waves?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I am currently trying to start a research project, and this is the most important question that needs to be answered. I cant't move ahead without knowing the chemistry of the brain.

Comment: brain waves [as per title] and chemistry [as per question body] are related but not identical. Tip: google 'brain waves' and see what pops up. The first hit is likely to be very useful. As of now this question is too broad and unclear. I would advise editing it to make it fit the [conventions of this site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Cells in the brain communicate with each other through [electrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential) (and [chemical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmission)) signals. The electrical signals from millions of neurons add up, and can be detected from outside the skull. This is called [electroencephalography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography).

The signals that are strongest when measured in this way are often [periodic or oscillatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_oscillation) (i.e. wave-like), because similar electrical signals from many neurons support each other if they are active synchronously. In contrast, when neurons are firing in a disordered way, then their electrical signals can partially cancel each other out when measured from outside the skull.